# Is a nook reader app for ubuntu touch being developed?

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-touch

I have a library of nook books and would like to read magazines on an Ubuntu touch Nexus 7.  Does anyone know whether a Nook app is on the cards?

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for the **ASUS Nexus 7** (with Ubuntu **14.04**) would be your starting point, with the question as written. *You would need to be patient ..*

---

A better question might be: 
***Is there a Nook-reader app. for Ubuntu?***

*Have you tried **Calibre**, to convert from the Nook format?* (ignoring DRM)

*Have you gone to the Nook support forums, and asked about Linux readers*? (addressing DRM issues)